# The right way to extract a list of attributes from a list of maps in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm looking for a non-ugly way to extract a list of particular values from a list of maps in Ansible. I can find *some ways* to do it, for example here: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45678882/ansible-jinja2-map-nested-key-in-list), but everything I have seen is very ugly, and it feels like there should be a way where it is clearer what is being done to someone reading it in future. I could write a filter, but it feels like this should be unnecessary since this must come up relatively regularly.

I have a data structure like so in Ansible:

```
interfaces:
  - name: eth0
    subnet: 192.168.2
    netmask: 255.255.255.0
    static_dhcp_hosts:
      - {name: "hosta", mac: "00:01:02:03:04:05", ip: "192.168.2.20"}
  - name: eth1
    subnet: 192.168.5
    netmask: 255.255.255.0
    static_dhcp_hosts:
      - {name: "hostb", mac: "00:02:03:04:05:06", ip: "192.168.5.20"}
      - {name: "hostc", mac: "00:03:04:05:06:07", ip: "192.168.5.21"}
```

I'd like to get a space separated list of the interface names, so

```
eth0 eth1
```

Obviously this is just example data, the actual top level list has 10 elements for one host. I know that I can use the join filter to get from a list of interfaces to the string I want and how to do that.

Can anyone suggest a nice way to make the list, that is readable to future maintainers (code/configuration should be self-documenting as far as possible (and no further))?

I am looking to do something like

```
{% for interface in interfaces %}{{ interface.name }} {% endfor %}
```

or

```
" ".join([ interface['name'] for interface in interfaces ])
```

in Python.

but, AFAIK, you can't, or it is considered bad practice to, use jinja2 loops like this in a role's task/main.yml, and, as I said, it feels like it shouldn't be necessary to use a custom filter for this.

(This role isn't just configuring a DHCP server, so please don't just suggest a pre-existing role that does that, that wouldn't solve my issue).

Any non-ugly way to do this would be much appreciated, as would confirmation from people that there is no non-ugly way.

I am using Ansible 2.3, but I'm interested in answers still even if they only work in later versions.

Edit:

The following:

```
"{{ internal_interfaces | items2dict(key_name='name',value_name='name') | list | join(\" \") }}"
```

works, and is the least ugly I can think of. It makes a dictionary from the list, with both the key and values being from the name attribute of the dictionaries in the list, and then casts this dictionary to a list, which just gives a list of keys. I'd still like something less obtuse and ugly if anyione can think of anything, or for any Ansible gurus to reply if they think there is nothing nicer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Map and join is what you require:

```
- set_fact:
    interface_names: "{{ interfaces | map(attribute='name') | join(' ') }}"
```

Comment: It is in the playbook itself that I need the space-separated string value. your answer, which I am only now seeing after posting my own answer, works fine though where I need it (adding on the join filter). Thanks. Happy to accept your answer, but it answers a slightly different question. If you want to edit it, I'll accept it (I'm not sure, does that give you some kind of karma, I don't use SO much).

Comment: "{{ interfaces | map(attribute='name') | join(\" \") }}" is what I needed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I had seen the Jinja template string in your question and assumed that the ultimate use would be in a template. But yeah, as you say, if you just want the space separated string in your playbook, join is the way to go. Edited.

Comment: I should probably have avoided that to avoid the confusion, but, yes, it is in the playbook I need it. Thanks. I've set your answer as the answer. I've up voted it, but my own reputation is too low for it to add to the score.

Comment: Note: `map(attribute='name') | unique | join(' ')` if you need to remove duplicates like I did.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I am being stupid. There is a nice way to do this:

```
"{{ interfaces | map(attribute='name') | join(\" \") }}"
```

The output from map is a generator which generates a list of the interface names, and join turns this into the string I want. Perfect.